# Sorting by translated enum

Tags: java, sql, oracle11g

I'm having a following problem: I have to sort entities by enum parameter. The thing is, that enum name is not equivalent to its translated name, for example, the enum values can be:

```
enum Sample {
  Bus, Car, Train
}
```

However, let's say in my language, `Bus` corresponds to `pks`, `Car` to `auto`, and `Train` to `ciuchcia`, co their order should be:
`Car, Train, Bus` and not `Bus, Car, Train`. It's just an example, my problem involves something like 10 different values.

The problem is, I can't get all the data, then perform a sort in Java, because the data is paginated. I tried to solve this problem by doing this in SQL (the data is from database view):

```
(CASE sample WHEN 'Car' THEN 1 WHEN 'Train' THEN 2 WHEN 'Bus' THEN 3 ELSE 0 END)
```

I'm sorting by number, and this solution works. However, I feel like this can be done better, and doesn't need to be modified each time I want to add something. Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: It sounds like you want to go this on the database server, so then it’s a sql problem, not a java problem. Please tag your question appropriately

Comment: Can't you just have a lookup table with the English and (your language) words, include it in a join, and sort on the (your language) word?

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem I have lookup table, but it has something like 50k+ records, and I feel like joining with it would greatly slow query time. Also, it's stored in two tables (one for texts with names, and the second with its translation, so it would be two joins instead of one).

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem Can't you lookup the order for each enum value for each locale once at application start?

Comment: @Dargenn 50K rows in a properly designed database is almost nothing. And vice versa, if your database has bad design, you will have problems sooner or later.

Comment: If a database table has an appropriate index, then the cost of the join will be minimal, even if there are 50k rows.  I would recommend replacing the English name with a key to a table that has both the English name and the name in your language.

Answer (score 0):

If you can hard-code or populate the translation in the `enum` you can make the `enum` generate the query.

```
enum Sample {
    Bus("pks"), Car("auto"), Train("ciuchcia");
    private final String localName;

    Sample(String localName) {
        this.localName = localName;
    }

    private static final List<Sample> inLocalOrder = Arrays.stream(values())
            .sorted((a,b) -> a.localName.compareTo(b.localName))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    public static CharSequence inLocalOrder() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("(CASE");
        int i = 1;
        inLocalOrder.stream().forEach(a -> sb.append(" WHEN '"+a.name()+"' THEN "+i));
        sb.append(" ELSE 0 END)");
        return sb;
    }
}

public void test(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(Sample.inLocalOrder());
}
```

prints:

> (CASE WHEN 'Car' THEN 1 WHEN 'Train' THEN 2 WHEN 'Bus' THEN 3 ELSE 0 END)

If the translations happen later then a minor adjustment should suffice.

Comment: The data is stored as database view (so it's only SQL) and I'm using Hibernate Criteria to query it. If I were to build query on the go, your solution would be perfect.

Comment: @Dargenn - Couldn't you build the `inLocalOrder` list during initialisation?

Comment: Do you mean to modify the database view, and then just query it in the code?

Comment: @Dargenn - Perhaps - or use this enum to create a table that directly translates `enum` name to sort order and use that table in your view.

Comment: @Dargenn - It does sound to me like you really do need two database lookups. A 50k table sounds huge but properly indexed it should work fast, even with double joins.

Answer (score 0):

First things first. Why you're using an Enum to sort stuff? I can't agree with this feature, but it's ok if you really need it.

I really appreciate @OldCurmudgeon's answer, but I would have done something different.

Instead of using the property value as the column name, I would use a method to request the correct column name (obviously I'm supposing that you don't have the entities mapped inside your code, so you're using an Enum to sort them). This way:

```
enum Sample {
    Bus, Car, Train;

    public String getColumnName() {
        // GET IT FROM SOME RESOURCE OR REQUEST IT FROM ANOTHER CONTEXT OR JUST RETURN IT THE WAY IT IS
        // YOU CAN USE A RESOURCE FILE TO MAP YOUR COLUMN NAME, SO IF THE ENTITY CHANGES, YOU DON'T NEED
        // TO UPDATE YOUR CODE...
        return "";
    }

    public static String getSortSQL(Map<Sample, Integer> samples) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("(CASE");
        samples.forEach((sample, number) -> addSampleNumberSQL(sb, sample, number));
        return sb.append(" ELSE 0 END)").toString();
    }

    private static StringBuilder addSampleNumberSQL(StringBuilder sb, Sample sample, Integer number) {
        return sb.append(" WHEN '").append(sample.getColumnName()).append("' THEN ").append(number);
    }
}
```

As you can see, you can request your column name from any resource you want. But this implementation still weak because if you need to sort by any new column, you will need to add another `Enum` value. So I would implement something more powerfull, like a properties reader that read each property from the resource and a method that receive an `String` (mean the property itself) and a number (to sort by the number) so I would do something like this:

```
public static String getSortSQL(Map<String, Integer> properties) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("(CASE");
    properties.forEach((prop, number) -> addSampleNumberSQL(sb, prop, number));
    return sb.append(" ELSE 0 END)").toString();
}

private static StringBuilder addSampleNumberSQL(StringBuilder sb, String property, Integer number) {
    return sb.append(" WHEN '").append(property).append("' THEN ").append(number);
}
```

Hope it helps you...